# What mode should I use when I create a folder for uploaded files

Tags: php

I have this directory structure:

```
\htdocs
\htdocs\uploadfiles\
```

Now if a user's id is s001, then I should create a new folder for this user to store uploaded files.

```
\htdocs
\htdocs\uploadfiles\
\htdocs\uploadfiles\s001\
```

Here are my questions:

```
Q1> What mode should I use for \htdocs\uploadfiles
Q2> What mode should I use for \htdocs\uplaodfiles\s001\
```

Based on `http://www.elated.com/articles/understanding-permissions/`
The function I use to create the folder for the user is as follows:

```
mkdir("/htdocs/uploadfiles/s001/", 0700);
```

That means only the owner of the s001 has access read/write/execute. But I don't know whether or not this is correct and practical.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. Make the owner of the directory the same user as the web server. Add ACLs to all of the directories if you need other users to have access.

Comment: Hello Ignacio,

I have mixed answers here. Still waiting for more explanation. One more question, what is ACLs?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The will be 777 to /uploadfiles and rest 755 while creating folder

mkdir("/htdocs/uploadfiles/s001/", 0755);